# Why does wget still print to stderr when there are no error and using -nv?

Tags: wget

I have a question illustrated by the following command line interaction:

```
$ wget www.google.com -nv >> out.log
2014-10-28 21:41:43 URL:http://www.google.com/ [17700] -> "index.html.1" [1]
```

So wget www.google.com, and using -nv (nonverbose, but still printing error information), and i redirected all the output to out.log, so nothing should print on stdout, but information still gets printed to the terminal, which i can only assume is coming from stderr. Does anyone know why wget does that? How would i go about turning it off and still preserve error logging when there are actual errors?

Thanks a lot!

Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use cURL instead:

```
$ curl -Ss http://www.stackoverflow.com -o /dev/null
(no output)

$ curl -Ss http://www.stackoverflow.invalid -o /dev/null
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'www.stackoverflow.invalid'
```

If you for whichever reason really need to use wget, you can capture output and only show it on failure:

```
errors=$(2>&1 wget -nv http://www.stackoverflow.com) || echo "$errors" >&2
```

Answer (score 3):

Like [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Logging-and-Input-File-Options) says, the option you are looking for is `-q`. "Non-verbose" merely turns off *verbose* status reporting.

The somewhat weird design decisions in `wget` are one reason to prefer `curl`.

Comment: OP wants to show error messages on error, but `wget -q http://www.stackoverflow.invalid` does not print any.